# VBA loop dynamic named range

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

Can someone please help with a named range loop to lock cells in a column.

I think I the problem might be at 'XXXXXXXXXX ??????  XXXXXXXX or Dim RngName As String

```
Sub Lock_Named_Range()
    Dim UserRow, SheetCol As Long
    Dim RngName As String
    With Sheet1
    UserRow = .Range("B8").Value
    For SheetCol = 8 To 13
        RngName = .Cells(4, SheetCol).Value
        If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ð" Then
            Range(RngName.Name).Locked = False 'XXXXXXXXXX ??????  XXXXXXXX
        End If
        If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ï" Then
            Range(RngName.Name).Locked = True 'XXXXXXXXXX ??????  XXXXXXXX
        End If
    Next SheetCol
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range(RngName).Locked = False` is the syntax... a string does not have a `.Name` property. This assumes `.Cells(4, SheetCol).Value` contains the name of the `Range` (notice the period before `Range` - that's what makes it use `Sheet1` instead of `ActiveSheet`)

Comment: I would suggest recording a macro while doing what you want, then fix it and post it here for improvements. What I see resembles more to "code map" than actual code...